# How to get the displayed div after scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one-page web site. It has 5 `div`, each with its content. I would like to know which `div` is displayed after user scrolls.

Comment: Please look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: An [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) might work for this but you'll need to provide your code if you want us to help.

Comment: You might also consider the jQuery inView plugin. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used .is(":visible") with good results:

```
if ($("#id_of_item_to_check").is(":visible"))
    doSomething();
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you wanted to, say, set a background-color to blue for the visible divs, and red for the others, you could:

```
$.each("div", function( key, value ) {
   if ($(this).is(":visible"))
      $(this).css("background-color","blue");
   else
      $(this).css("background-color","blue");
});
```